# Advisory speed limits on turns

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, everyday-life, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

I was just thinking about why many corners have advisory speed limits that are less than the highway speed limit, does it have to do with centripetal acceleration?

Comment: Reduced forward vision around the corner is sometimes a factor in vehicle speed reduction...

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with this:

In a perfect world, turns would all be *banked* so you could traverse each at full speed and not skid sideways off the road. Since it is not always possible to bank the roadway surface at the right angle to support a full-speed turn, the reduced speed limit in a turn is set to accommodate the existing bank angle and turn radius minus a safety factor which includes wet pavement, bad driving habits, and poor tires.

Comment: Going into a banked turn at *less* than the physically appropriate speed puts *extra* demands on road/tire friction...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is a maximum acceleration  that your tires can provide.Be careful with sharp turns at high speeds where the centripetal acceleration is close to this limit. Any additional acceleration (or breaking) may cause the vechicle to slip out of the turn.

If you decrease your speed, centripetal acceleration decreases and you will be more safely within the capabilities of your tires in case you need to do a sudden change of direction/speed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to do with the ability to stop if something is in the road. One night I was driving around a corner at the suggested speed then I saw a tree in the road. I was able to stop a couple feet in front of tree.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).